# Magento : JQuery & Infinite Ajax Scroll not working with LAYERED NAVIGATION

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I am using the FME filter and the infinite Ajax scroll.
https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html

Basically i want to use the side filter + load more products when scrolling (using jQuery).

Initially, It is working proper and bind the product as per pagination when I am selecting and deselecting product using filter.
but once i'm scrolling to load more products it's not loading and the load more progress button is not visible.

Is there is a url problem ? or class / Id issue with jQuery? that prevent more product to be loading?

Can someone help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Niv
I have not used this layered navigation, but you can check for any jQuery conflict or you might get any error for any method that is not defined. You can check it in console of a browser.

Hope this might help you to diagnosed your problem more clear